# AWS CodeDeploy for Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-virtual-machine, aws-code-deploy

this might come off as a rather far fetched query but please help me out.

Is it possible to register an Azure Virtual Machine with AWS CodeDeploy?

I've done some read up and found that Amazon provides option to install the CodeDeploy agent on On-Premises instances as seen [HERE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/on-premises-instances-register.html)

If it is at all possible, how do we go about it?

My objective is to try and use CodeDeploy as we are already subscribed to it instead of using Azure's DevOps services.

Comment: sure, why shouldn't this work? Just assume your Azure VM is "on-premises" and follow the guide for that

Comment: @silent Thanks i'm gonna have to try it out I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @silent, I tried it out and it actually works. Here are the steps:

But before we start, MIND YOU!: [image]

Step 1: Install AWS CLI

Step 2: Configure AWS with a user that has the role of the CodeDeploy IAM user

Step 3: Run the following command

```
  aws deploy register 
  --instance-name <some name for your VM> 
  --iam-user-arn <IAM user arn> 
  --tags Key=<some key for you tag>,Value=<some value> 
  --region <your region>
```

Step 4: run `aws deploy install --config-file codedeploy.onpremises.yml`

Comment: when you say "install AWS" I assume you mean "AWS CLI"?!

Comment: @silent yeah noticed that. Just changed it :)